# Regex case insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

How do I put this regex in case insensitive?

```
var message_id = result.match(/Message-Id\:(.*)/)[1].replace(/^\s+/, '');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the `i` flag:

```
/Message-Id\:(.*)/i
//                ^
```

[Documentation →](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Or start your regex with (?i) as in /(?i)Message-Id.../